# Word for "to appear suddenly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The only word I can think of is *pop up* (and maybe *materialized*).

Are the other words?

Example sentence:

> The ghost __ in front of her.

Comment: Can you tell us why *appeared*, *popped up*, and *materialized* don't work for you in this context? For example, maybe you want something with a different feel or level or formality, or implying a different amount of time to appear? Also, did you look up any or all of these in a Thesaurus? If so, what was wrong with what you found there?

Comment: "Burst into sight" is another term that comes to mind.

Comment: To manifest....

Comment: Honestly, "appeared" -depending on context- usually implies "suddenly" but why not just use "suddenly appear"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***[Materialise](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/materialize)*** will fit in your sentence:

> If an object materializes, ***it appears suddenly***:
>
> - Suddenly a lorry appeared in front of her - it seemed to materialize out of nowhere.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

see usage examples [here](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22ghost%20materialized%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1932,cd_max:1997&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=5drTWKmlOYPiU9z7pZAF):

> - The creature paused to listen, its twisted, bat- snouted face grimacing. ***Mrs. Seward's ghost materialized*** beside that of her killer
> - Then a blue sheet, in ***the shape of a ghost, materialized before them***. "

Comment: Can ghosts be said to materialise, unless it becomes corporeal? *(of a ghost, spirit, or similar entity) appear in bodily form.*
‘he plays a teenager whose make-believe friend materializes’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/materialize

Comment: @Spagirl - ever heard of figurative usage?

Comment: Why is the most upvoted answer the word that the OP says they have already thought of? The question is "Are there other words?" – this answer does not even try.

Comment: @theonlygusti  - because OP is not sure about it (maybe materialised) while, as a matter of fact, it is probably the more appropriate term in this case.

Comment: @Josh no, in fact the question is "are there other words?"  It is not "hey what do you think is better out of these two words I've already thought of myself?"

Comment: @Lee - that's the way I understand the question, and that is the term I'd use. All other suggestion do not appear to be a better alternative. OP is clearly undecided about its usage. My answer should help in this case. Note that it is the only term that literally means "appear suddenly", just the definition OP is looking for.

Comment: @Josh - It's not a matter of interpretation, his question was precise and you simply did not answer it.  Also not true it's the only match: "Instantaneous transformation or appearance" also fits even if you don't like it.  Was your answer helpful?  I don't know, but no one is arguing that point.  To be clear, the question was why is your answer voted highly when it was not in fact, an answer?  My guess is people just thought materialize sounded good (so do I) and didn't realize you weren't the one who suggested it.

Comment: @Lee - OP SAYS "maybe materialized" suggesting a doubt. My suggestion is that the word materialized is a very good fit. Why should I suggest another that is not  as  good? Anyway that is my answer, if you disagree please downvote it.!

Comment: Again, no one said you should suggest an answer not as good.  Moreover it would be lovely to add supportive comments aiffirming OP's musing.  It's just weird for a full post response not to include an answer to the question.

Comment: "Materialize" does not connote suddenness. When it is used for a sudden event, the suddenness comes from context, not from the word "materialize".

Comment: @MetaEd I agree, a simple dictionary lookup confirms this. Also Josh, all your examples are about ghosts (as is the OP's case,) where materialize has a specific meaning very different to appearing suddenly. In fact, it's not even _implied_ that any of those ghosts are appearing suddenly.

Answer (score 8):

How about [*spring up* (Merriam-Webster):](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spring%20up)

> :  to grow or appear suddenly ▪ The weeds *sprang up* overnight. ▪ New housing developments are springing up all over the state.

References to ghosts springing up in literature (emphasis mine):

> It was, however, all in vain; a veritable **ghost sprung up**, seized him […]
>   [(‘A Restored Invalid’, *The Metropolis of The Water Cure*, 1858.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=fBwDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22ghost%20sprung%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipjubC6OzSAhWDyyYKHTaJC5UQ6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=%22ghost%20sprung%20up%22&f=false)
>
> Meanwhile, Thalia’s classmates were wide-eyed and petrified, as if their long-lost teacher were a **ghost sprung up** behind them, mouth full of dry yolk.
>   [(Tom Bradley, *Killing Bryce*, 1999.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dEm6latL-tQC&pg=PA251&dq=%22ghost%20sprung%20up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipjubC6OzSAhWDyyYKHTaJC5UQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=%22ghost%20sprung%20up%22&f=false)

Answer (score 8):

Would you accept a made up word if it was from a well-known series of books, and hence understandable to most people? I suggest **[apparate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apparate)**:

> Verb
>
> 1. (neologism) To appear (magically); to teleport to or from a place.

<sup>wiktionary</sup>

It is from the Harry Potter series, and is clearly inspired by words such as "appear" and "apparition".

Comment: apparate was my first thought too

Comment: Henry Potter has been read by most people?  I don't think so.

Comment: @Lee I agree that most people probably haven't read **Henry** Potter. Notwithstanding your typo, I didn't say most people had read Harry Potter either, I just said that a word from the series would be understandable to most people. All that given, you're probably right that using "most" might be stretching it a bit, but hey.

Comment: Not everyone has ever seen Star Trek. I'm prettY sure everyone has heard "Beam me up, Scotty."

Answer (score 3):

Some choices I like:

[arose](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arose): `The ghost arose in front of her.`

Basically a minor variation on 'sprung up'.

[erupt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erupt): `The ghost erupted in front of her.`

Maintains the desired quickness, if not violence, the author is seeking with "spring up", although I think it would be better to restructure the phrase a bit to make this fit more sensibly, such as "the ghost erupted from the ether before her."

[coalesce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coalesce): `The ghost coalesced in front of her.`

This doesn't really maintain the sense of quickness as 'sprung up', if anything it sounds rather lazy, but i think it's a fitting choice for a ghost. It has this suggestion of the ghost's form pooling inwards after being spread out, similar to materialize but has a more poetic feel to it.

Comment: Erupt conveys suddenness, but coalesced and arose suggest an observable transition into being, rather than an instant appearance.

Answer (score 2):

Geek-culture jargon provides:

> [**bamf**](http://catb.org/jargon/html/B/bamf.html) /bamf/
>
> 1. [*from X-Men comics; originally “bampf”*] interj. Notional sound made by a person or object teleporting in or out of the hearer's vicinity.
>      Often used in virtual reality (esp. MUD) electronic fora when a
>      character wishes to make a dramatic entrance or exit.

It'd imply a noisy sort of ghost, perhaps the shade of a munitions expert...

Answer (score 2):

Snapped into view could work similarly to sprung or popped up

Comment: Snapped has many meanings, including a sudden sharply worded response, a sudden breaking or fracturing, a sudden loud noise, etc. It always indicates a sudden and possibly unexpected effect of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

*I turned around and **shazam** she was there.*

**shazam** - used to indicate an instantaneous transformation or appearance

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shazam)

Answer (score 1):

**Conjure** *something up* [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjure?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)

> to make (something) appear or seem to appear as if by using magic

*A ghost was conjured up in front of them.*
I have to add though, it is mostly used in the sense - *to make sth pop up as if by magic.*

Comment: Yes, conjure is more in line with the "ghost" theme. However, it does not seem quite right in this context, because the emphasis is on some outside force that *made* the ghost appear, rather than appearance itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sudden, but, with the sample sentence, I rather like `coalesce`.

```
As she stood transfixed, the ghost coalesced in front of her.
```

> Come together to form one mass or whole.   ‘the puddles had coalesced
>   into shallow streams’
>
> Combine (elements) in a mass or whole.    ‘his idea served to coalesce
>   all that happened into one connected whole’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coalesce

Comment: From "coalesce" I infer "appears slowly" not "appears suddenly". That said, [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quickly+coalesced%2Cslowly+coalesced%2C+suddenly+coalesced&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquickly%20coalesced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslowly%20coalesced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuddenly%20coalesced%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that it is just as common with the adjectives "quickly", "slowly" or "suddenly", so maybe it's just me. Or maybe it needs the adjective to avoid implying "slowly".

Comment: Yes, I would agree that it "feels" slow - at least it is a noticable process (+1).